# Custom Keyboard in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

iOS 8 lets us create our own custom keyboards.
Is it possible to make a custom keyboard output anything other than unattributed NSStrings?

Can I make a keyboard that outputs images to say the Messages app, or is it impossible?

Comment: You can output ascii art. :-)

Comment: FYI - you really should ask this on the Apple dev forums since you are not supposed to discuss new APIs. Read the NDA you agreed to with Apple.

Comment: @rmaddy well a lot of prerelease docs are available even without the NDA

Comment: Yes, also you can ask a question without ever having signed an NDA, so he is allowed to discuss it, people answering most likely aren't. Haha!

Comment: I wonder how they made this then.. http://popkey.co/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this would be too difficult since most `UITextField` / `UITextView` can only handle `NSString` object.

As described in the [`UITextDocumentProxy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextDocumentProxy_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextDocumentProxy/documentContextBeforeInput) only `NSStrings` are allowed.

`UITextDocumentProxy` is the communication object used by [`UIInputViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIInputViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIInputViewController/textDocumentProxy). `UIInputViewController` seems to be the base for creating custom keyboards.

Also have a look at [App Extension Programming Guide
 - Custom Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW1)

Comment: How do emojis currently work? I assume that there is a specific sequence of characters that represent each emoji. Does the system simply replace this sequence with an image?

Comment: emojis are unicode characters, and are handled by the system. In OSX they are replaced by an images. I've also seen some font to support them where they are just fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a twitter-style workaround: when the user selects an image, you upload it to your server and send a shortened url in reponse. this shortened url will be inserted to the text view of the host app and good luck :)

Comment: @jasper - looks like popkey give a grid of images that the user copy pastes into his text field

Comment: You were correct about that. But now I found a new app, which does not need full access, so they actually can't use the UIPasteBoard. They use custom fonts but I don't understand how this can work, even without the recipient not having the font at all.. You got any idea? http://ios.wonderhowto.com/how-to/use-custom-fonts-for-messaging-your-iphone-0157819/

Comment: It seems like they just used unicode to 'fake' a custom font